# (async () => { })(); what is this?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
async function test() {
  (async () => {            
    var a = await this.test1();
    var b = await this.test2(a);
    var c = await this.test3(b);  
    this.doThis(a,b,c);                              
  })();
}
```

What does it mean to put methods (test1,test2,test3) inside `async () => {})()`?
I find it faster than

```
async function test() {          
  var a = await this.test1();
  var b = await this.test2(a);
  var c = await this.test3(b);  
  this.doThis(a,b,c); 
}
```

Any downside of using it?

Comment: It just seems faster because the returned promise doesn't doesn't actually wait for any of your sequential logic. You might as well change it to a synchronous function since the returned promise is basically a `return Promise.resolve();` in the first case, which isn't useful at all.

Comment: if it's not useful at all, when should one use `(async () => { })();`?

Comment: At the top level, when you want access to `async` / `await` syntax. If that expression exists within another function, it means the caller of that function will not be able to know when the asynchronous calls have completed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both return a promise but they return different promises.

The first will return a promise that may resolve before `this.test1()`'s result resolves.

The second returns a promise that only resolves after the final call to `this.doThis(a,b,c);`.

This has been called the "[fire and forget pattern](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2018/11/13/c-async-fire-and-forget/)":

> Often in application development you want a process to call another thread and continue the process flow, without waiting for a response from the called thread. This pattern is called the “fire and forget” pattern.

You can see this in

```js
function logEventually(str) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(str);
      resolve(null);
    }, 0);
  });
}

async function a() {
  await logEventually('in a 1');
  await logEventually('in a 2');
  await logEventually('in a 3');
  return await logEventually('end of a');
}

async function b() {
  (async () => {
    await logEventually('in b 1');
    await logEventually('in b 2');
    await logEventually('in b 3');
  })();
  return await logEventually('end of b');
}

a();
b();
```

Comment: Thanks. still not so sure when should one use `(async () => {})();`

Comment: So if it resolves `this.doThis(a,b,c);` even before it resolves `this.test1();`, doesn't it mean that `this.doThis(a,b,c);` would error out?

Comment: @bbusdriver I added a note about the "fire and forget" pattern.  I think it fits what's going on in your example.

Comment: @bbusdriver Your question doesn't make any sense. It can never resolve `this.doThis(a,b,c);` before it resolves `this.test1();`. Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: @MikeSamuel in regards to the "fire and forget" pattern, isn't the outer function generally synchronous? There's no reason for it to return a promise that doesn't actually wait for anything.

Comment: @bbusdriver.  The promise returned by the whole may resolve before test1 resolves.  The chain of awaits within the inner lambda still proceed in the order implied by the `await` statements.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, normally you'd do some work after the self-invoking lambda.  I don't think it has to be synchronous though to qualify as an instance of the pattern.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks. I have another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014143/async-vs-callback)