# (async () => { })(); vs callback

Tags: javascript, callback, async-await

```
async function test() {
  for (var i = 0; i < balance; i++) {      
    (async () => {            
      var a = await this.test1(i);
      var b = await this.test2(a);
      var c = await this.test3(b);  
      this.doThis(a,b,c);                              
    })();
  }
}
```

So I've concluded that `(async () => {})();` is quite similar to a good old callbacks

```
function test() {
  for (var i = 0; i < balance; i++) {      
    test1().call().then((a) => {           
      test2().call(a).then((b) => {
        test3().call(b).then((c) => {
           this.doThis(a,b,c);   
         });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Is this right? performance-wise I find they are about the same.

1. Do they have any differences?
2. What pattern should I follow?

I want to go with the first one `async/await`, but if I take out `(async () => {})();` I find it slower to render stuff in UI compare to the second one.

Comment: If you add some loops / ifs, thats easy to do with the first pattern but it gets pain with the second. Some say that `async/awaut` is *just* syntactic sugar, while that applies to some cases (e.g. yours) it doesn't really apply to more complicated ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do they have any differences?

You should `return` from the `then` callbacks so that errors do propagate properly. Apart from that, they're basically equal.

> What pattern should I follow?

Both of them are [fire-and-forget calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572), on which you should not forget to 
 handle errors!

> I want to go with the `async/await`, but if I take out `(async () => {})();` I find it slower

Sure, because then you are `await`ing in the loop so it's becoming sequential.